# Caching of arbitrary functions and values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, caching, hash

I am working on a cache handler class that given an arbitrary function and a set of arguments caches its result. This will be used in a load-balancing MPI scheduler written in python. Although the program will be run on multiple process, only a master process will have a working function of this class.

The scheduler allows to submit a task (func, args) and returns an instance of an MPIFuture object that will in the future hold the result. I want to cache these (func, args) to return a saved MPIFuture object instead of recomputing the result.

I have multiple implementations of this class using cachetools and functools, yet for the sake of argument I have implemented a simple example using a dictionary.

```py
from .MPIFutures import MPIFuture, MPIFutureArray
import dill
import hashlib
import numpy as np

class CacheHandler():
    def __init__(self, scheduler):
        self.sched = scheduler
        self.cache = {}

        if self.sched.is_master():
            print("Caching is enabled!")
    
    # ======= Forward methods =======
    def compute(self):
        self.sched.compute()

    def init(self):
        self.sched.init()
    
    def finalize(self):
        self.sched.finalize()
    # ======= END =======

    # ======= Redefine methods =======  
    def submit_multiple(self, func, *args):
        return MPIFutureArray([self.submit(func, *domain) for domain in list(zip(*args))])

    def _generate_key(self, func, args):
        # Serialize the function and arguments using dill
        serialized_data = dill.dumps(args)

        # Generate a hash of the serialized data
        data_hash = hashlib.sha256(serialized_data).hexdigest()

        return (func, data_hash)

    def submit(self, func, *args):
        # Get hash
        key = self._generate_key(func, args)

        # Check if result has been cached already
        if key in self.cache.keys():
            return self.cache[key]
            
        # Submit work to the scheduler and cache returned future
        future = self.sched.submit(func, *args)
        self.cache[key] = future
        
        return future
```

When testing this implementation with simple MPI benchmarks, it produces the correct results, yet when I implement it into the main MPI application code, it fails to find any cache hits (always misses).

To see what was going on, I modified the class to this:

```py
from .MPIFutures import MPIFuture, MPIFutureArray
import dill
import hashlib
import numpy as np

class CacheHandler():
    def __init__(self, scheduler):
        self.sched = scheduler
        self.cache = {}
        self.f = []
        self.x = []
        self.h = []
        if self.sched.is_master():
            print("Caching is enabled!")
    
    # ======= Forward methods =======
    def compute(self):
        self.sched.compute()

    def init(self):
        self.sched.init()
    
    def finalize(self):
        self.sched.finalize()
    # ======= END =======

    # ======= Redefine methods =======  
    def submit_multiple(self, func, *args):
        return MPIFutureArray([self.submit(func, *domain) for domain in list(zip(*args))])

    def _generate_key(self, func, args):
        # Serialize the function and arguments using dill
        serialized_data = dill.dumps(args)

        # Generate a hash of the serialized data
        data_hash = hashlib.sha256(serialized_data).digest()

        return (func, data_hash)


    def submit(self, func, *args):
        # Get hash
        key = self._generate_key(func, args)

        if key in self.cache.keys():
            print("Found cached results!")
            return self.cache[key]
            
        print("Result not found, computing...")
        future = self.sched.submit(func, *args)
        self.cache[key] = future
        
        print(f"FUNCTION: {fi in self.f} ARGS: {xi in self.x} HASH: {hash(key) in self.h} ")
        self.f.append(fi)
        self.x.append(xi)
        self.h.append(hash(key))

        return future
```

Eventually, the program starts outputting the following:

```
...
Result not found, computing...
FUNCTION: True ARGS: True HASH: False 
Result not found, computing...
FUNCTION: True ARGS: True HASH: False 
Result not found, computing...
FUNCTION: True ARGS: True HASH: False 
...
```

This indicates that the functions and arguments are indeed the same, yet the hash of a tuple containing the two is not. For the sake of testing I even tried replacing `func` with `func.__name__` and I got the same result. Most of the time the arguments are one or more numpy arrays. I also tried converting `args` to a tuple before serialisation but that did not help.

At this point I am not sure what is happening. I am not able reproduce the issue in my minimal working examples.

Can any Python expert give me a hint on what is wrong here?

#### EDIT 1:

Here is an example benchmark I tested:

```py
class T():
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 1
    def f(x):
        print("COMPUTING F")
        return x


test = T()

x0 = np.array([1., 2., 3.])

# Submit a first time
sched.submit(test.f, x0)
sched.compute()

# Alter state of the object
test.k = 2

# Submit a second time
sched.submit(test.f, x0)
sched.compute()
```

This produces the following correct results:

```
mpirun -np 2 python test.py 
Using MPI scheduler.
Caching is enabled!
Result not found, computing...
FUNCTION: False ARGS: False HASH: False 
COMPUTING F
Found cached results!
```

Comment: does your data (arrays) contain floats?  Equality testing of floats is unreliable.

Comment: Yes, however the code does not directly compare floats.
Numpy float arrays are serialised and then a sha256 hash function is calculated based on the byte-values of the objects. If the hashes match then it is virtually guaranteed that the two objects are bit-wise identical. The output of the program does show that the sha256 hashes are identical.

Also I specifically tested for this in a minimal benchmark and did not encounter any issues.

Comment: In general, `hash` is very rarely the thing you want. try `print(hash(-1) == hash(-2))` to be confused, then move to hashlib.

Comment: @Carbon yeah the python hash function is a bit... meh...
Yet dicts use the built-in hash function so I am stuck with that.

I thought about building my own dictionary data-structure or something but there must be a better way.

Comment: numpy arrays can't be used a `dict` keys..  They aren't hashable, because they are mutable.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, that is why I serialise them. Once I have converted a numpy array to a sequence of bytes then it becomes hashable. For numpy arrays specifically one can use the arr.tobytes() method, while for more general objects I used dill to serialise them.

Comment: but if there are small variations in the floats (the reason we use `np.isclose`), the serielized versions will differ, and the hashes won't match.

Comment: @hpaulj that's fine. In my case I only cache results for byte-identical input. If you look at my test you can see that the sha256 hashes do match, yet the python hash functions still generates a different result. It seems like even if the function and sha256 hash are the same, python cannot reliably map (func, sha) tuples as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I know that the arguments of the functions I have to cache are mainly numpy arrays, I decided to redesign the class to leverage the `arr.tobytes()` function instead of serialisation via dill.

I am not sure what the major difference from the old implementation is, but this works correctly.

```py
from .MPIFutures import MPIFuture, MPIFutureArray
import numpy as np
from cachetools import LRUCache, MRUCache, RRCache
import hashlib
from math import floor, log10

class CacheHandler():
    def __init__(self, scheduler, tol=1e-6, eviction_strategy = "RR", max_cache_size=1000):
        self._sched = scheduler
        self._dec = self._tol_to_dec(tol)
        self._cache = {}
        self._maxsize = max_cache_size
        self._evict = eviction_strategy

        if self._sched.is_master():
            print("Caching is enabled!")
            print(f"Tolerance set to {self._dec} decimals precision (tol = {tol})")
            print(f"Eviction strategy set to {self._evict}")
    
    # ======= Forward methods =======
    def compute(self):
        self._sched.compute()

    def init(self):
        self._sched.init()
    
    def finalize(self):
        self._sched.finalize()
    # ======= END =======

    # ======= Helper functions =======
    def _tol_to_dec(self, tol):
        if tol > 0:
            return -int(floor(log10(tol)))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Tolerance must be a positive number.")
        
    def _hash_args(self, args):
        # Serialize args
        serialized_args = [np.round(arg, decimals=self._dec).tobytes() for arg in args]

        # Generate a hash of the serialized data
        hashes = [hashlib.sha256(arg).hexdigest() for arg in serialized_args]
        return "".join(hashes)

    def _get_new_cache(self):
        if self._evict == "LRU":
            return LRUCache(maxsize=self._maxsize)
        elif self._evict == "MRU":
            return MRUCache(maxsize=self._maxsize)
        elif self._evict == "RR":
            return RRCache(maxsize=self._maxsize)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown eviction strategy {self._evict}")
    
    # ======= Redefine methods =======  
    def submit_multiple(self, func, *args):
        return MPIFutureArray([self.submit(func, *domain) for domain in list(zip(*args))])
    
    def submit(self, func, *args):
        # Can only cache functions with numpy arguments
        if any(not isinstance(arg, np.ndarray) for arg in args):
            return self._sched.submit(func, *args)

        # Function not cached yet
        if func not in self._cache.keys():
            self._cache[func] = self._get_new_cache()
        
        # Generate hash for args
        hash = self._hash_args(args)
        
        # Use the key to attempt to get the result from the cache
        future = self._cache[func].get(hash)

        # Cache miss
        if future is None:
            future = self._sched.submit(func, *args)
            self._cache[func][hash]= future

        return future
```